# Notify on ArrangeOverride

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, itemscontrol

I have an items control with custom panel. Based on this itemsControl I am writing an Behavior (Behavior)
What I need is whenever arrange override for my ItemsPanel is called my behaviour should get notified. In my behavior I have access to the itemsControl and the itemsPanel.

One way is I can raise an event from ItemsPanel override and subscribe it in my Behavior.

But if you there is a better solution please can you suggest?

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I would try to do it:

1. Create a "fake" control

   ```
   class ArrangeNotifier : Control
   {
       public event EventHandler OnArrange;
       protected override ArrangeOverride(blabla)
       {
           (OnArrange??delegate{})(blabla);
       }
   }
   ```
2. On your "OnAttached" of your behavior, create a `var myNotifier = new ArrangeNotifier()` that you will add to the panel AttachedObject (which obliges your behavior to be a `Behavior<Panel>`)
3. Suscribe to myNotifier.OnArrange from your behavior, and do your stuff in the handler
4. Do not forget to remove your fake control in "OnDettached" of your behavior

**[Edit]** I misread your question, I guess that this was what you suggested :)
I dont see any another way.

Comment: thanks for looking Olivier but this not what i am looking for.